# How do I handle a calender without a massive 12x12 switch statement?

Tags: c, date, struct, switch-statement

I'll be heading to some tutoring tomorrow, but I'd like to see if I can get an explanation here. Tried to ask a friend from my class, but explanation didn't make sense.

I'm supposed to take the user's input in the form of a structure that holds day, month, and year.

Here's all I really have right now:

```
enum month
{
        JAN = 1, FEB, MAR, APR, MAY, JUNE, JUL, AUG, SEPT,
        OCT, NOV, DEC
};

struct date_t
{
        unsigned short month;
        unsigned short day;
        unsigned short year;
};

int main(void)
{
        date_t date; /*Allocates space for 3 unsigned shorts,
        all for the date*/

        printf("Please enter the month as an integer: \n");
        scanf("%hu");

        printf("Please enter the day as an integer: \n");
        scanf("%hu");

        printf("Please enter the year as an integer: \n");
        scanf("%hu");

        return 0;
}
```

So, here's my issue.

I could write an absolutely massive 12x12 (144 options) switch statement for every single case of month + zodiac sign combination, but that's just insanity. I really don't know what to do here.

The idea is if the user entered:

```
8 (month)

28 (day)

12 (year)
```

My program should output:

```
August 28th, 2012, Virgo
```

The main issue is that we haven't learned a way to store strings as a variable yet. That's past what we've done.

So I could make one switch statement with 12 cases (one for each month) and give each one a different "printf" statement starting with 
("Month %d, %d", date.day, date.year)

But then how do I do the zodiac sign? Also, that's 12 cases, that feels a little ridiculous.

My teacher suggested something about converting to Julian dates, and I almost understand how, but it seems like I'd need a really complicated for loop with a switch statement or a bunch of if/elses in there.

What in the world am I doing wrong? What is the simpler solution?

EDIT:

I managed to solve 2/3 of my problem. Now I'm running into a different one.

I need to deal with leap years (whatever that means) and find their sign. Gah.

EDIT 2: Figured it out! Wish I could show you all the code without making this post absolutely absurdly long. It works though! Very happy! Now I need to make a menu system for it. ;-;

Comment: I would suggest having three separate arrays, one for each field, that you fill up at the beginning of your program and then using the scanned numerical input to index into the corresponding array. Edit: and use their inputs to calculate the zodiac sign

Comment: You don't have to print the result all at once.  So it really isn't 12x12 cases, it is 12+12 cases.

Comment: Hmmm `scanf("%hu");` needs work.

Comment: How does scanf("%hu"); need work? That's the proper form for an unsigned short.

Comment: Where to put the result?  Try `scanf("%hu", &date.month);`

Comment: Thanks! Just noticed that myself, but now I've run into an issue where during compiling it complains that date isnt a structure. Argh.

Comment: EDIT: Fixed that, now I see another issue: printf("%hu", &date.day"); It flips out, saying that it's not of the correct type.

Comment: EDIT: fixed that as well. Was a goof on my part. Didn't need the &.

Comment: It looks as though the answer below put you on the right track for your solution. So it might be a good idea to accept it and by that declare the question solved.

Answer (score 4):

I think you are thinking that you have to make a print statement that prints the whole line at once, but you can have multiple print statements, each which just prints part of the line.

Since this is a learning exercise, I don't want to give too much away, but realize that you could print your answer like this:

```
printf("August ");
printf("28th, ");
printf("2012, ");
printf("Virgo");
printf("\n");
```

Comment: Wow. I feel like an idiot. That never came to mind, but that makes it far, far more simple. Thank you.